# In a Flutter app using Firebase email authentication (with SMS multi-factor activated) how can I update the phone number used for multi-factor?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

In my Flutter app I'm using Firebase Autentication with Email/Password as providers. Also, I've implemented the SMS Multi-factor Authentication.
What's the proper way to update, from the code, the phone number used for SMS Multi-factor Authentication?

I've tried to solve this by using `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` (passing the new number) and inside `codeSent` to perform

```
await user.updatePhoneNumber(PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode!,
));
```

but it didn't work.